# My "prompt" won't load on the web page after i added the if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

So i tested the prompt alone and it worked fine but after i added the text afterwards nothing seems to be loading. Please help.

```js
var myage = parseInt(prompt("enter age ", 30), 10);

if (myage >= 0 && myage <= 10) {
  document.write("myage is between o and 10 <br/>");
}

if (!(myage >= 0 && myage <= 10)) {
  document.write(" myage is not between 0 and 10 <br/>");
}

if (myage >= 80 || myage <= 10) {
  document.write("myage is equal to or above 80 or 10 or less");
}

if ((myage >= 30 && myage <= 39) || (myage >= 80 && <= 89)) {
  document.write("myage is between 30 and 39 or myage is " + "between 80 and 89");

}
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error in the last `if` test.  That's why you should always have the developer console open.

Comment: cheers i know its a trivial mistake but it thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

In the last `if` statement, you forgot to add my `myage` to the value check; you just wrote the `<=` operator without the value of variable to compare with.

You should open the console when you are debugging. The console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=", which would lead you to the line where the problem occurred.

Change

```
if ((myage >= 30 && myage <= 39) || (myage >= 80 && <= 89/*missing variable to check the value of*/)) {
  document.write("myage is between 30 and 39 or myage is " + "between 80 and 89");

}
```

To

```
if( (myage>=30 && myage<=39)||(myage>=80&&myage<=89)) {
      document.write ("myage is between 30 and 39 or myage is " + "between 80 and 89");
}
```

```js
var myage = parseInt ( prompt("enter age ", 30) , 10);

if (myage >= 0 && myage <= 10) {
  document.write("myage is between o and 10 <br/>");
}

if (!(myage >= 0 && myage <= 10 )){
  document.write(" myage is not between 0 and 10 <br/>");
}

if (myage>=80||myage<=10) {
  document.write("myage is equal to or above 80 or 10 or less");
}

if( (myage>=30 && myage<=39)||(myage>=80&&myage<=89)) {
  document.write ("myage is between 30 and 39 or myage is " + "between 80 and 89");
}
```

Comment: yep that was it cheers for the help. I can finally move on from this

Comment: @TheoBrown No problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `myage` at last condition.

```js
var myage = parseInt(prompt("enter age ", 30), 10);

if (myage >= 0 && myage <= 10) {
  document.write("myage is between o and 10 <br/>");
}

if (!(myage >= 0 && myage <= 10)) {
  document.write(" myage is not between 0 and 10 <br/>");
}

if (myage >= 80 || myage <= 10) {
  document.write("myage is equal to or above 80 or 10 or less");
}

if ((myage >= 30 && myage <= 39) || (myage >= 80 && myage <= 89)) {
  document.write("myage is between 30 and 39 or myage is " + "between 80 and 89");

}
```